# Vue onclick filter

Tags: java, vue.js, button, filter

Dear Stack Overflowuser,

Under this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EskoNielson/pd19o8we/261/) is a code, with which a onclick filter in Vue JS was tried to built. However, the approach does not function yet.

The JS is in lines 118 - 120. Code obtained from [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EskoNielson/e0Luo7v3/).

Code is only in the jsfiddle, since posting the code is due to Stack Overflow functions not possible.
Thanks in advance for any help that makes the onclick filter work in the jsfiddle.

Desired result is a click function showing only the products with a merchant, which is the name of the button.

Yours sincerely

Esko Nielson

Comment: have you seen this guide? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if code is visible here. Then it might be easier to help and communicate about the code.

Comment: the fiddle didn't work for me. I see this `<a class='gotoLine' href='#423:26'>423:26</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null"` I see code mix between Vue, jQuery and VanillaJS dom manipulation. I recommend to refactor everyting to Vue only.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code, that prevent you from getting the wanted result:

- You mix Vue methods with regular window methods. The `filterSelection` method is defined **twice** - first as a part of Vue `methods` definition, and then again afterwards. What you will notice is that just the second one gets called.
- You use regular js functions to modify the DOM. That is very contrary to what VueJS is doing. Instead of adding or removing classes with custom made methods, you could use [the proper way Vue does that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html): `class="{ show: propertyFromVue }"`. This would toggle the `show` class on and off, based on the `propertyFromVue` boolean value.
- The list of toppings is defined once and just displayed. You need a **second** variable that holds only the "filtered" items. This could be done through a computed property:

  ```js
    computed: {
      filteredToppings: () => this.toopings
        .filter((topping) => !!topping.vendors
          .find((vendor) => vendor.merchang === this.filterSelectionText)
        );
    }
  ```

  This would **only** work if your VueJS `filterSelection` method is called and `filterSelectionText` property is updated.

  Then you can use this `filteredToppings` to display the list of filtered items :) Good luck!

Comment: Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gq0bLm2r/1/ You were using `onclick` which is **not** Vue way to do it. You should use `@click`. Read the Vue documentation first. Also there was some code at the bottom that does some really weird things. I've commented it as it fired errors. Good luck!